# partial fraction decomposition special case

Tags: partial-fractions

I would like to have the following partial fraction decomposed : $$\frac{2r+1}{r^2{(r+1)}^2}$$  Since the denominator does not contain any constant the approch is non-trivial to me.
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hint: $(r+1)^2 - r^2 = 2r + 1$

Comment: The approach is the same it always is: write it as $\frac{Ar+B}{r^2}+\frac{Cr+D}{(1+r)^2}$, and solve for $A,B,C$ and $D$.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is clear now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\frac{2r+1}{r^2(r+1)^2}=\frac{(r+1)^2 - r^2}{r^2(r+1)^2} = \frac{1}{r^2} - \frac{1}{(r+1)^2}$$

Comment: Thanks again, this helped a lot.